# 'Authorization' header sent with request, but missing from apache_request_headers()

Tags: php, apache, http-headers

I'm sending an Ajax request to my PHP/Apache server. The request contains an `Authorization` header, as shown below in a screenshot from my browser's dev tools:

[image]

When testing against my local Apache server, I can access the `Authorization` header fine from PHP using [`apache_request_headers()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php). However, on my production server (on shared Linux hosting) the header is missing from the array returned from `apache_request_headers`, which looks like this:

```
array(10) {
  ["Cookie"] => string(31) "_ga=GA1.2.1071821587.1446317606"
  ["Accept-Language"] => string(14) "en-US,en;q=0.8"
  ["Accept-Encoding"] => string(19) "gzip, deflate, sdch"
  ["Referer"] => string(27) "http://goaunited.com/admin/"
  ["User-Agent"] => string(110) "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"
  ["Accept"] => string(33) "application/json, text/plain, */*"
  ["Cache-Control"] => string(8) "no-cache"
  ["Pragma"] => string(8) "no-cache"
  ["Connection"] => string(5) "close"
  ["Host"] => string(13) "goaunited.com"
}
```

Why is the `Authorization` header not included in the `apache_request_headers()` response on my production server? What could be causing it to be omitted?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

After some quick search found setting a rewrite rule works

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
 </IfModule>
```

Can anyone tell me what it does ?

Comment: Some headers aren't available to CGI and other scripts. This copies one of them so it is available in the environment.

Comment: I have done this, but the problem persists! Is there any other solution I should try out?

Comment: "RewriteEngine On" just turn on or off the rewritting engine, if you want to disable all rewrite rules then set it off. RewriteRule as documentations says is the real workhorse, your pattern is .* (zero or more characters), substitution is not done because the dash and as 3rd parameter "flags" it sets a environment variable "[E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:" with values in header "%{HTTP:Authorization}]".

Answer (score 13):

Yep..

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

or

```
SetEnvIf Authorization .+ HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$0
```

..in .htaccess works for me..

Answer (score 5):

I edited my .htaccess file as below. Then
adding the last line solved the issue.

```
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [QSA,L]
    SetEnvIf Authorization .+ HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$0
```